# Projecting lines onto surface in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, elevation, guatemala

I am designing a water distribution system for a rural village in Guatemala.  I have created contours for the area.  I need to lay out the pipe routes and need to know how to get the elevation of the lines to determine pressure drops in the system.  I assume I create a TIN surface and project my lines onto the surface.

How do I do that?

Go from a contour shapefile to a polygon surface and then draw the lines and project them onto that surface.

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissetzfromraster